# Why do streaming services or platforms fail with big events?

Tags: streaming, twitch, traffic, network-traffic

I'd like to know and understand technically why streaming services struggles in big events and what the difference is between TV and streaming services. Technically speaking, in terms of networks, traffic, apps, etc.

For example, a few days ago, the Spanish streamer [Ibai](https://www.twitch.tv/ibai) hosted a big event on the Twitch platform. It was a stream with 3.4m viewers or so (a record for the platform).

The experience was awful, lag, cuts, freezes, etc. It's an Amazon company; they are "the internet". I mean, they have the servers.

They said in response to Ibai that **"it is hard to host a stream like that"**...

So what could happen? Why is it hard? I mean having all the power and servers they have.
Why the classic TV doesn't have these problems? Why can everybody watch the super bowl without cuts in a traditional TV channel?

I remember watching the FIFA world cup ("soccer") last year through streaming services. I suffered cuts and freezes too.

What are these streaming services lacking? I want to learn this from a technical point of view.